# How to print page/node templates being used on a page?

Tags: theming

I'm using Drupal 6.19 and trying to debug why a custom page template for my login page isn't being picked up.
I've tried to use devel themer, but I don't see the "widget" when I'm not logged in, and of course I can't see the login page when I am.

I'm hoping for a script that I can drop in on my page tpl that will print the current template being used. Or maybe there are other suggestions?

Comment: What is your Template filename, and what is your URI? If Devel is installed try a dpm(); output: https://drupal.org/node/174575

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 7, there's a new 'theme debug mode'. This eliminates the need for installing the Theme Developer module and its dependencies, if all you want is to see the templates being used on a page.

> As of Drupal 7.33, Drupal core has a theme debug mode that can be
>   enabled and disabled via the theme_debug variable. Theme debug mode
>   can be used to see possible template suggestions and the locations of
>   template files right in your HTML markup (as HTML comments). To enable
>   it, add this line to your settings.php:

```
$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

see https://www.drupal.org/node/223440

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [Theme Developer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module.

> Firebug for Drupal themeing. Note that this module injects markers
>   into the DOM to do its magic.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I've touched 6, so vars may be different than I recall, but you could use:

```
print_r($variables['theme_hook_suggestions']);
```

Inside of a preprocessor function. That will tell you what the system is trying to use. At that point I'd look for the files and put insert in 'This is path/to/file.tpl.php' in the templates.

Hope that helps.